# Building sample software with unicode

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unicode

I'm starting to develop a Windows service using the sample code provided by Microsoft. I've compiled the resource only DLL, but I'm getting errors when I build the first file provided here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/svc-cpp

I'm getting several errors related to converting different string data types:

Here is an example line of code:

```
SvcReportEvent(TEXT("RegisterServiceCtrlHandler"));
```

Which is producing this error:

```
E0167   argument of type "const wchar_t *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPTSTR"
```

Here is another example:

```
SvcReportEvent(TEXT("StartServiceCtrlDispatcher"));
```

It is producing this error:

```
E0144   a value of type "const wchar_t *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "LPWSTR"
```

And this one:

```
if (!GetModuleFileName("", szPath, MAX_PATH))
```

is producing this error:

```
C2664   'DWORD GetModuleFileNameW(HMODULE,LPWSTR,DWORD)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [1]' to 'HMODULE'
```

My project is set to use the Unicode character set in the Project Properties dialog. I expected the sample code to build without problems, so I didn't want to go in and start converting or casting the variables to fix the problems. I feel like there must be a setting or something I need to change.

What is the best way to deal with these errors?

Comment: These are all pointers to `const` that need a pointer to non-`const` passing.  Unicode is a miss-direction.  Please post a [mcve] of the lines in question.

Comment: SO is littered with questions about this symptom ,thus do a search (which you should have done already) and you surely will find an anwer for your problem.

Comment: Project > Properties > C/C++ > Language > "Conformance mode" = No.  You'll have to fix the GetModuleFileName mistake by yourself.

Comment: Change `SvcReportEvent` to take a parameter of type `LPCTSTR` (note the `C`). Pass `NULL` as the first argument to `GetModuleFileName`, in place of the empty string.

Comment: Thank you, Hans Passant. That was the main problem. Thank you also to Igor Tandetnik for the tip on GetModuleFileName too. I really appreciate your assistance.